# Merging boxplots from two variables

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a data set that like this:

```
Group  ripk2pre ripk2post  HDAC2PRE HDAC2POST TNFalfapre TNFalfapost  hdac1pre hdac1post
1      0 1.2953928 1.3764571 2.0882699 1.3751473  1.3707263  0.9081135 1.0558543 0.9428877
2      0 0.9123888 1.2130447 0.8429092 1.0029163  1.2713608   1.2682995 1.0769362 1.2495874
3      0 1.2437122 0.8164699 1.9392855 0.7427853  1.0119777   2.0928740 0.8362260 1.5880373
4      0 0.8352961 1.0609110 0.9104137 1.2687785  0.8347809   0.8345946 1.5121548 1.1003785
5      0 1.0563645 1.2732350 1.2210999 2.1879613  2.2030366   1.0042444 0.7399383 0.7093015
. 
.
.
```

So what I would like to do, is representing, for each pair (ripk2pre/ripk2post), a boxplot near each other. So I have two boxplots inside the same graph box, with x labels showing for example (pre-treatment and post-treatment), and a title showing "ripk2 gene expression".

I know how to do it separating by group variable, but I do not want to do this, but kind of merging a boxplot graph with two boxplots for each pre and post variable together, so as the label in x is not divided by group (this is the way I know), but divided by pre and post treatment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that you are looking for this but check it out

```
det <- read.table(header = T, stringsAsFactors = F,  text = "
Group1 Group  ripk2pre ripk2post  HDAC2PRE HDAC2POST TNFalfapre TNFalfapost  hdac1pre hdac1post
                  1 0 1.2953928 1.3764571 2.0882699 1.3751473  1.3707263  0.9081135 1.0558543 0.9428877
                  2 0 0.9123888 1.2130447 0.8429092 1.0029163  1.2713608   1.2682995 1.0769362 1.2495874
                  3 0 1.2437122 0.8164699 1.9392855 0.7427853  1.0119777   2.0928740 0.8362260 1.5880373
                  4 0 0.8352961 1.0609110 0.9104137 1.2687785  0.8347809   0.8345946 1.5121548 1.1003785
                  5 0 1.0563645 1.2732350 1.2210999 2.1879613  2.2030366   1.0042444 0.7399383 0.7093015")

library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
det %>% select(Group, ripk2pre, ripk2post) %>%
  melt(id.vars = c("Group")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = value)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for, but now, I have another data.frame with the same variables, but corresponding to another group 1, so that I would like to paste another two boxes boxplot near this one, so I can compare both group 0 and group 1. I mean, putting the same boxplot but corresponding to the group 1, near the created one.

Comment: use `facet_wrap(~Group1)` earlier include Group1 in the `melt` and `select`

Comment: if the answer was of any help for you, you can acknowledge it by marking it